# regex - lazy and non-capturing

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, scripting, vbscript

String to search:

```
VALUES ('9gfdg', to_date('1876/12/06','YYYY/MM/DD'), null)
```

Regex search so far:

```
VALUES\s*\(\s*'?\s*(.+?)\s*'?\s*,\s*'?\s*(.+?)\s*'?\s*,\s*'?\s*(.+?)\s*'?\s*\)
```

Regex replace to 3 groups: ie `\1 \2 \3`

I am aiming for a result of:

```
9gfdg to_date('1876/12/06' ,'YYYY/MM/DD')  null
```

but instead get (because of that extra comma in to_Date and also lazy instead of greedy):

```
9gfdg to_date('1876/12/06 YYYY/MM/DD , null)
```

Note:
It is exactly 3 fields (the values within th 3 fields may be different but you get the idea of the format I am grappling with). ie each of the fields could have commas (usually character values, could be a keyword such as null, could be a number or could be a to_Date expression.

Regex engine is VBA/VBscript

Anyone have any pointers on fixing up this regex?

Comment: Is there anyway to make the commas greedy but the single quotes lazy?

Comment: See my answer, it should fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

Notice the regex for `$field`: it is yet another application of the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern, with `normal` being anything but a comma (`[^,]`) and `special` a comma as long as it is not followed by two single quotes (`,(?!'')`). The first `normal`, however, is made non empty using `+` instead of `*`.

Demonstration code in perl. The string concatenation operator in perl is a dot:

```
fge@erwin $ cat t.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl -W
use strict;

# Value separator: a comma optionally surrounded by spaces
my $value_separator = '\s*,\s*';

# Literal "null", and a number
my $null = 'null';
my $number = '\d+';

# Text field
my $normal = '[^,]'; # Anything but a comma
my $special = ",(?!'')"; # A comma, _not_ followed by two single quotes
my $field = "'$normal+(?:$special$normal*)*'"; # a text field

# A to_date() expression
my $to_date  = 'to_date\(\s*' . $field . $value_separator . $field . '\s*\)';

# Any field
my $any_field = '(' . $null . '|' . $number . '|' . $field . '|' . $to_date . ')';

# The full regex
my $full_regex = '^\s*VALUES\s*\(\s*' . $any_field . $value_separator . $any_field
    . $value_separator . $any_field . '\s*\)\s*$';

# This builds a compiled form of the regex
my $re = qr/$full_regex/;

# Read from stdin, try and match (m//), if match, print the three captured groups
while (<STDIN>) {
        m/$re/ and print <<EOF;
Argument 1: -->$1<--
Argument 2: -->$2<--
Argument 3: -->$3<--
EOF
}
```

Demonstration output:

```
fge@erwin ~ $ perl t.pl
VALUES ('9gfdg', to_date('1876/12/06','YYYY/MM/DD'), null) 
Argument 1: -->'9gfdg'<--
Argument 2: -->to_date('1876/12/06','YYYY/MM/DD')<--
Argument 3: -->null<--
VALUES('prout', 'ma', 'chere') 
Argument 1: -->'prout'<--
Argument 2: -->'ma'<--
Argument 3: -->'chere'<--
VALUES(324, 'Aiie, a comma', to_date('whatever', 'is there, even commas'))
Argument 1: -->324<--
Argument 2: -->'Aiie, a comma'<--
Argument 3: -->to_date('whatever', 'is there, even commas')<--
```

One thing to note: **you will notice that I don't ever use any lazy quantifiers, and not even the dot!**

edit: `special` in a field is actually a comma not followed by *two* single quotes, not one

Comment: +1 - but it puts quotes around the strings - want it not to returns quotes around 9gfdg

Comment: Well, you could just substitute `^'` and `'$` for nothing in captured fields ;) After all, nothing other than text fields will match these two regexes.

Comment: And even more: how would you then distinguish a number, like `234`, from its string representation, like `'234'`?

Comment: in all those cases would like to strip out the outside quotes

Comment: thanks- just before I accept your answer: what would be the modification required for to_date('1876/12/06','YYYY/MM/DD') to just return '1876/12/06' or 1876/12/06 (either is fine while still supporting null, digits.etc)?

Comment: This is another thing which is better left post-matching. If you really want to alter the results like this, you are far better off with a completely different process: remove `VALUES(` from the beginning, create as many regexes as necessary (one for number, one for null, etc), match against each separately, until you reach the end of arguments. But that's for another question, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If only the second parameter can have commas in it, you could do something like:

```
^VALUES\s*\(\s*'?([^',]*)'?\s*,\s*(.*?)\s*,\s*'?([^',]*)'?\s*\)$
```

Otherwise I don't know what features that regex flavor supports, so hard to make something more fun. Altho you could always make a limited depth nested parentheses regex if `(?R)` is not supported.

Comment: almost but not quite. It gives:  9gfdg to_date('1876/12/06' YYYY/MM/DD , null)

Comment: @toop, forgot to anchor the regex, try now.

Comment: better! but it does not work if you switch around the fields (like swap the 1st and 2nd fields around). Do you know a way to support all 3 formats?

Comment: @toop, could do a more complex expression, do you know if `(?|...)` and `(?R)` are supported? I guess they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

For the more general case you could try something like:

```
^\s*
VALUES\s*
\(
\s*
(?: '([^']*)' | ( \w+ (?: \( [^()]* \) )? ) )
\s*,\s*
(?: '([^']*)' | ( \w+ (?: \( [^()]* \) )? ) )
\s*,\s*
(?: '([^']*)' | ( \w+ (?: \( [^()]* \) )? ) )
\s*
\)\s*
$
```

Spaces removed:

```
^\s*VALUES\s*\(\s*(?:'([^']*)'|(\w+(?:\([^()]*\))?))\s*,\s*(?:'([^']*)'|(\w+(?:\([^()]*\))?))\s*,\s*(?:'([^']*)'|(\w+(?:\([^()]*\))?))\s*\)\s*$
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2 \3\4 \5\6
```

Should work for one nested level of parentheses without any quoted parenthesis in them.

PS: Not tested. You can usually use the spaced regex if your flavor supports the `/x` flag.

Comment: +1 - but does not handle one embedded single quote. ie 'tes't'

Comment: @toop, how should that be handled? Example please. Looks like syntax error to me.